# Building a Windows Server 2008 R2 (DNS, DHCP, AD, etc...)

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, dhcp, replication

I'm looking forward to build my own Windows Server 2008 R2 machine for a company that is in the process of establishment.

I have some questions regarding the Windows Server. I'm pretty new to it .. I need to be able to achieve the following ..

First, regarding the DHCP, I was able to build a simple one on a VM. But, I need to have multiple subnets, each in a different VLAN (different departments of the company). Is this done on the Server Level or the Network Level?

Second, I'm looking to have couple of local/public web-servers, probably VMs, I want to have the public servers to be accessible from the internet, while the local to be only accessed from the network.

for example, I have `web.intra.lcoal` as my local server and `www.website.com` as my public, how can I achieve this using a local DNS? I have read something about having a nameserver ..

Also, if I'm looking for a redundancy for the DHCP and DNS, how can I achieve this?

Last but not least, how can I create an AD Server?

I know how to install the services on the Windows Server, but I'm not able to configure them.

Best Regards.

Comment: Don't use made up TLDs like .local. As for the rest of this - you're basically asking how to become a Windows sysadmin. In my opinion, this question is **way** too broad to be asked on a website like this, you should get some training.

Comment: @MDMarra I will use this in my local network only, will not be used publicly ..

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's internal only. It's a violation of more than one RFC and you shouldn't use it anywhere. http://www.mdmarra.com/2012/11/why-you-shouldnt-use-local-in-your.html

Comment: Why are you segregating the departments into separate VLAN's?

Comment: @joeqwerty this is a network design requirement that I have done .. Plus, I'm looking forward for expanding and having more than one location where I will be using Centralized DHCP, or might perform failover between Servers on separate locations (still reviewing it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will answer the question, but you probably won't like how broad the answers are. There have been books written about what you're asking. No one is going to give you a step-by-step.

> First, regarding the DHCP, I was able to build a simple one on a VM. But, I need to have multiple subnets, each in a different VLAN (different departments of the company). Is this done on the Server Level or the Network Level?

Both. You need IP Helpers on your switches and the scopes configured on the server.

> for example, I have web.intra.lcoal as my local server and www.website.com as my public, how can I achieve this using a local DNS? I have read something about having a nameserver

Don't use a made up TLD. Have separate DNS servers for internal and external and use a firewall to keep the internal servers from being exposed to the Internet.

> Also, if I'm looking for a redundancy for the DHCP and DNS, how can I achieve this?

By having more than one and configuring the HA option of your choice for each. Consult the documentation for these.

> Last but not least, how can I create an AD Server?

You read the documentation. Do it in a lab. Follow best practice as published by Microsoft, then you implement it. Or you hire someone that knows what they are doing to assist.

Comment: Can you provide documentations (if possible)?

Comment: Microsoft provides all of their documentation for free at http://technet.microsoft.com

Comment: and what about the nameserver? I read that I should use it to have my domain point to my public IP .. Is that correct? If so, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Seriously. Read the documentation. Are you not embarrassed to ask others for help before you've tried to help yourself? DNS servers are required for name resolution. If you don't know that, you really should hire a contractor to assist you.

Comment: IP helpers on routers, not on switches per say.. the switch could be a router however :)

Comment: Well on your L3 switches (which are technically routers, since they route but are typically different in software and hardware spec than edge routers) :)

Comment: pauska, MDMarra, I'm building my network using Cisco Devices (Routers/Switches and possibly Cisco ASA).